# Predicting equality/inequality of integrals of multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to predict equality/inequality, of indefinite integrals of multivariable fucntions, over a domain from equality/inequality respectively of those functions over the same domain?

**Does f(x,y,z) ≠ g(x,y,z) for say x,y,z belonging to the set of natural numbers ⇒ ∫∫∫ f(x,y,z) dx dy dz ≠ ∫∫∫ g(x,y,z) dx dy dz for x,y,z belonging to the set of natural numbers?**

While this should hold for definite integrals, this does not look binding for indefinite integrals. But, I was just wondering if it was possible, if not in general, then in some special cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Can we conclude from this that ∫∫∫ f(x,y,z) dy dx dz ≠ ∫∫∫ g(x,y,z) dy dx dz for x,y,z belonging to the set of natural numbers?". I suspect that there is some serious sort of misunderstanding of integrals behind this question. For indefinite integrals, you can always add a constant.

Comment: I simply mean does f(x,y,z) ≠ g(x,y,z) for say x,y,z belonging to the set of natural numbers ⇒ ∫∫∫ f(x,y,z) dy dx dz ≠ ∫∫∫ g(x,y,z) dy dx dz for x,y,z belonging to the set of natural numbers? I thought my meaning was quite obvious. As for my misunderstanding of integrals, quite certainly there is. Last time I studied them was 8 years ago :O